# Generating JAXB classes with XML

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have an XML document, with some first lines like this: (giving a internet explorer screenshot because it highlights nicer, the content is also available at the bottom as text)

[image: Screenshot]

I want to generate a nicer way to parse these specific Invoice documents. It gives its own schema location in first line, `Invoice-2` so I googled it and found the following document: http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.0/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.0.xsd. I tried to execeute xjc to create classes, but it did not find the other required classes for it: (they are on the web, but how can I download them all or just tell xjc to look from the docs.oasis-open.org?)

```
# xjc UBL-Invoice-2.0.xsd
parsing a schema...
[WARNING] schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document '../common/UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
  line 21 of file:/root/abc/UBL-Invoice-2.0.xsd
```

We are also given some XSD files by government in http://efatura.gov.tr/dosyalar/kilavuzlar/e-FaturaPaketi.zip but none of them has `UBLTR-Invoice-2.0.xsd` in them. I just want to ask, is this schema `Invoice-2` or `UBLTR-Invoice-2.0.xsd`?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Invoice xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 UBLTR-Invoice-2.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:ubltr="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:TurkishCustomizationExtensionComponents" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
<ext:UBLExtensions>
<cbc:UBLVersionID>2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
<cbc:CustomizationID>TR1.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
<cbc:ProfileID>TEMELFATURA</cbc:ProfileID>
.......
```

I really need some pointers, I do not have enough experience with XML/XSD and any directions would be nice.

Comment: Did my suggestion work?

Comment: You may use https://github.com/phax/ph-ubl as the basis containing UBL 2.0 and 2.1 precompiled Java objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the following documents. I found the link to the documents in the header of the invoice. When you opened the documents just rightklick and save it them as name.xsd

Your needed xsd's:

- [Invoice](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.0/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.0.xsd)
- [CommonAggregateComponents](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/cs-UBL-2.0/xsd/common/UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.0.xsd)
- [CommonBasicComponents](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/cs-UBL-2.0/xsd/common/UBL-CommonBasicComponents-2.0.xsd)
- [UnqualifiedDataTypeSchemaModule](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/cs-UBL-2.0/xsd/common/UnqualifiedDataTypeSchemaModule-2.0.xsd)
- [CommonExtensionComponents](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/cs-UBL-2.0/xsd/common/UBL-CommonExtensionComponents-2.0.xsd)
- [QualifiedDatatypes](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/cs-UBL-2.0/xsd/common/UBL-QualifiedDatatypes-2.0.xsd)

Just add them to your project (all same directory). Then run xjc for the main xsd (Invoice) and you all should work fine.

Usually you don't have to download them manually but the reference is not made correct in the invoice so jaxb can't resolve the reference automatically.

If it still does not work, just edit the import paths in the invoice.xsd to match the data structure of the downloaded files.

Comment: "run jaxb for the main xsd" => "run **xjc** for the main xsd"

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools available (a quick google search should fetch you some) that can generate XSD from XML assuming string type for almost everything. You should be able to use that XSD to run JAXB to get classes.

Here's an online tool that lets you do that.

Comment: The problem is, as I mentioned that the links in the main xsd are relative, hence you cannot just parse the main file. So you have to download the files manually by googling the correct reference...